# Setting appropriate permissions on SU binary

Tags: rooting, file-permissions, superuser

I recently found a way to maintain root access on my android device using a dropbear SSH server that I modified to run at boot as root using init.d, a lil scripting magic & some config scripts I made. If you want you can check it out [here](http://goo.im/devs/Geofferey/Android%20Scripting%20Projects/persist_droid_sshd/v1.0/Universal-Flasher). Anyways for an experiment I removed the su binary and Superuser.apk from the system. I've managed to get them copied back to the system but I don't know the appropriate permissions for the su binary. If I look in Super User app on another rooted phone and go to update it shows `-rwsr -sr-x` as the permissions on the binary. How can I set these same permission manually & what do they mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For setting file permissions, you can use the `chmod` command. The permissions shown are basically split in 3 parts, each consisting of 3 chars: a triple for the owner, the group, and for "others". Usually, each triple holds definitions for reading, writing, and executing a file; so `rwx` means "can read, write, and execute", while `r--` would say "can only read".

The resulting 9 chars are usually preceded by another one, giving information of the type of the "file": (d)irectory and (l)ink are the most common examples. Again, if no "special condition" matches, a leading `-` indicates a "normal file".

Based on that, let's take your input: `-rwsr-sr-x` obviously describes a "normal file" (starting with `-`), readable (`r`) by owner, group, and others, writable by owner only, and executable by "others" ­– while owner and group have a `s` instead the `x` for execute. This stands for "suid", elevate the caller to the level of the file owner/group.

Taking advantage of the fact permissions can be set "bit-wise" (`x`=1,`w`=2,`r`=4, suid user=4, group=2), after my long "rant" finally the command which should do the trick:

```
chmod 6774 su
```

Should set the permissions your question shows. If I "mis-calculated", you've got all information to re-calculate for yourself now :)

---

***Additional hints from the comments:***

Instead of calculating the "bitmask", one can also use symbolic names – as [Dan Hulme](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/12442/dan-hulme) pointed out, and as explained e.g. on the [chmod manpage](http://www.ss64.com/bash/chmod.html):

- defining whom to grant to: (u)ser / (g)roup / (o)thers / (a)ll
- defining what to grant: (r)ead / (w)rite / e(x)ecute / (s)uid
- defining whether to (+)grant or (-)revoke

So the following two commands should be similar, provided there haven't been other things granted before:

```
chmod 6774 su
chmod u+rws g+rs o+rx su
```

The difference becomes clear in case e.g. before "others" had also write permission: while the first command (using a bitmask) sets the permission explicitly to match the "grants" defined (and thus would remove that write permission), the symbolic one "makes a diff" (in the example, it just *adds* the permissions specified to whatever was there before, so that write permission would not be removed).

Comment: You don't need to calculate the numbers for `chmod` yourself: `chmod u+rws g+rs a+rx su` will do exactly the right thing, and doesn't require you to count on your fingers.

Comment: Sure that it's not `chmod u+rws g+rs o+rx su` (not "all", but "o"thers, see [chmod manpage](http://www.ss64.com/bash/chmod.html))? I always mess that up thinking whether was it "owner" or "others", which is why I prefer using the bitwise stuff, except when only changing stuff for group ;)

Comment: @DanHulme checking with the manpage again, `a+rx` would set "rx" for "ugo" (user, group and others). I'm not sure which confuses me more: calculating the bit-set, or interpreting recursing symbols :P

Comment: Yes, using `a` would make the command shorter, but as you've noticed, it makes it a bit harder to see what is going on, so I almost never use `a`.

Comment: @DanHulme I didn't even know about the `a` symbol. But thanks for kicking me into checking the manpage again :D The `a` switch can be quite useful sometimes, for things like `chmod a+r public_info.txt`.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you were saying. Yes, when I wrote `a` in my first comment I meant `o` for others. I wondered why you brought it up!

Comment: Thanks for clarification, @DanHulme! With your permission (and credit given), I will include it with my answer, so nobody has to follow up all the comments for understanding.